# How to copy two dropdown value and get their selected value in another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have three dropdowns. What I want is when I select two dropdown values, their values will get in the third dropdown. I tried something but it's not correct.

```js
function copyDiv(){
      var size = document.getElementById('size');
      var color = document.getElementById('color');
      var data = document.getElementById('data');
      var amt = size.options[size.selectedIndex].value;
      var typ = data.options[data.selectedIndex].value;
      data.value += amt + typ;
    }
copyDiv();
```

```html
<select id="size">
<option >S</option>
<option >M</option>
<option >L</option>
</select>
<select id="color">
<option>Grey</option>
<option>Red</option>
<option>White</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="data">
<option>S / Grey</option>
<option>M / Grey</option>
<option>L / Grey</option>
<option>S / Red</option>
<optio>M / Red</option>
<option>L / Red</option>
<option>S / White</option>
<option>M / White</option>
<option>L / White</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add a value to a select, you can only change/add a value of/to an option.

I don't know what you need this for but to change the given options in the third select you need to alter it's innerHTML. innerHTML will replace everything between `<select id=...>` and `</select>`.

If you want it to be updated on every selection you will need to add an onChange=copyDiv() to the first two select fields.

Also the function is very confusing, if you give more information about what exactly you need this for and what you want to achieve it will be easier to provide help.

EDIT:

As I now know exaclty what you want, here a possible way to do what you asked for in the comments:

```html
<div>
        <select id="size" onChange="doJob()">
            <option>S</option>
            <option>M</option>
            <option>L</option>
        </select>
        <select id="color" onChange="doJob()">
            <option>Grey</option>
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>White</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id="sizeColor">
            <option id="0">S / Grey</option>
            <option id="1">M / Grey</option>
            <option id="2">L / Grey</option>
            <option id="3">S / Red</option>
            <option id="4">M / Red</option>
            <option id="5">L / Red</option>
            <option id="6">S / White</option>
            <option id="7">M / White</option>
            <option id="8">L / White</option>
        </select>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>
 <script>
        function doJob() {
              var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
            var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
            
            if(size.length !== 0 && color.length !== 0) {
                var sizecolor = size + " / " + color;
                for(let i=0;i<9;i++) {
                    var combined = document.getElementById(i);
                    if(combined.value == sizecolor) {
                        combined.selected = "selected";
                    }
                    else {
                        combined.selected = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: What I want is when I select the first two dropdown values, those information match with the third dropdown and update dynamically. If I select "M" and "Red" the third dropdown wold show the "M / Red".

Comment: Ok and you want the third droptdown still to provide the complete list?
If so, there are two options i can think of with that you can achieve this behaviour.
First option: you add an id to every single option in the third drop down, build a for loop and alter .selected when the value fits the variable with first and second dropdown combined.
Second option: you put all the options into an array and build up the complete option list of the third select with the selected one as the first option so it is automatically selected. 

I personally would give the first option a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very much clear, whether you want to add selected value to third dropdown or you want to change selection of third dropdown basis on the first two dropdown. If your 3rd dropdown is already populated and just want to change selection then find below quick snap of code.

```
 <div>
        <select id="size">
            <option></option>
            <option>S</option>
            <option>M</option>
            <option>L</option>
        </select>
        <select id="color">
            <option></option>
            <option>Grey</option>
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>White</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id="data">
            <option>S / Grey</option>
            <option>M / Grey</option>
            <option>L / Grey</option>
            <option>S / Red</option>
            <option>M / Red</option>
            <option>L / Red</option>
            <option>S / White</option>
            <option>M / White</option>
            <option>L / White</option>
        </select>
    </div>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#size").change(function () {
                PopulateThirdDDL();
            });

            $("#color").change(function () {
                PopulateThirdDDL();
            });
        });
        function PopulateThirdDDL() {

            var size = $('#size').val();
            var color = $('#color').val();
            if (size != "" && color != "") {
                var itm = size + " / " + color;
                $('select[id="data"]').val(itm);
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Can we add `this` keyword in the script?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve using 'this' keyword??